# (C#) "STATE_SYSTEM_BUSY" in automationElement.Patterns.LegacyIAccessible.Pattern.State

Tags: c#, winapi, ui-automation, microsoft-ui-automation

i am programming the uiautomation, but some applications that i used to test the uiautomation, the LegacyIAccessible.State contain STATE_SYSTEM_BUSY. I had tried to wait the more than 1hour. It still on busy. Any code related solution can solve this issue?

```
AutomationElement automationElement = objElement as AutomationElement;
return automationElement.Patterns.LegacyIAccessible.Pattern.State.Value.ToString();
```

Comment: Why do you need to use LegacyIAccessible with UI Automation?

Comment: Hi, for answer ur question. At beginning, i directly use uiautomation class, but didnt find the specific ui element. Uiautomation abstracted from LegacyIAccessible object, and LegacyIAccessible of the element is failed load.

Comment: *some applications that i used to test the uiautomation* -- what applications?  Possibly those specific applications have a bug or other problem that prevents them from interacting with the UIA framework.  A [mcve] that tells us exactly how to reproduce the problem would help clarify whether the issue is on your side or the application's side and so would increase your chances of getting help here.  See: [ask].

Comment: The issue that happened when I tested the whatsapp desktop version on my winserver/win8/win7, win10 did not had this related issue.